# Windows 8 requiring trailing dot in DNS name in order to resolve

Tags: networking, windows-8, dns, ping

I'm in the process of setting up a home network but I'm having issues on my Windows 8 machine.  If I ping another host on my network, the name won't resolve. If I use nslookup, it will resolve no problem.

After a bit of trial and error I tried adding a trailing dot to my host name when doing a ping.

Here is the results when I ping a machine named "**apex**":

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping apex
Ping request could not find host apex. Please check the name and try again.

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Here are the results when I ping "**apex.**":

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping apex.

Pinging apex [192.168.1.235] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.235: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.235: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.235: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.235: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.235:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\Windows\system32>
```

I've never encountered this problem before so I'm sure this interface is just configured improperly.

Answer (score -1):

Try `ipconfig /flushdns && ipconfig /registerdns` that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I actually tried this with no luck. Turns out WINS server was disabled on my router.